# Formatting Java record fields similar to classes with Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, record

I have the following code:

```java
record FooBar(@NotNull String foo, @NotNull Integer bar) {
}
```

I'd like Intellij IDEA to format it to:

```java
record FooBar(

    @NotNull 
    String foo, 

    @NotNull 
    Integer bar

) {
}
```

Is this possible?

The closest I was able to get is:

```java
record FooBar(
    @NotNull String foo, 
    @NotNull Integer bar
) {
}
```

which is not ideal as number of annotations can vary.

The options I used to get to this result are

```
Record components   Wrap always
Align when multiline    true
New line after '('  true
Place ')' on new line   true
```

Comment: I think you need to do one or more structural replaces to be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When positioning the cursor over one of the members and pressing the lightbulb, one can select "Put record components on separate lines". This reformats the code:

[image]

Before:

```
record FooBar(String foo, Integer bar) {

}
```

After:

```
record FooBar(
        String foo,
        Integer bar
) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently this doesn't seem to be supported - I've opened [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-298007/Formatting-Java-record-fields-similar-to-classes-with-Intellij-IDEA) on JetBrains issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

By checking checkbox "New Line after '(' as shown below:

[image]

Comment: But that will affect all method declarations, not only records (and it will not insert newlines after annotations).

Comment: Yes, after doing some digging it seems the main problem are annotations as none of the annotation options do anything in case of record components.